# What is ExpressionEngine's release cycle?

Tags: untagged

What is ExpressionEngine's latest position regarding their release cycle. Is there a public policy we can follow and hold them to?

Comment: I think this is a question better asked directly to EllisLab (derek.jones@ellislab.com). I'd suggest removing this question.

Comment: I agree. This is really a customer support issue which is outside the scope of this Q&A sites.

Answer (score 2):

The last we were told was 12 weeks but at this point you can't hold EL to much at all regarding internal operations.